# Printing RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, printing, telerik

I have a paged RadGrid with a PDF Export function (which is in the RadGrid by default). Now I want to have an print function too.
A print function is not availible by default in the RadGrid. Is it possible to print a paged RadGrid, or to immediately print the generated pdf (I don't know how to access the generated pdf).

Thank you in advance!

Kind regards,
Wesley Lalieu

Comment: This might help you http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/grid/print-radgrid-contents.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I described in my question: I have a paged RadGrid, and the code they have on that page is not compatible with a paged RadGrid. Someone or something else to try?

Comment: Agh, sorry missed that bit! Looks like it is not supported but this thread has a few suggestions http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/grid/72051-radgrid-print.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to try this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attached a demo that shows how to print the exported PDF file. I don't like this approach but it might be suitable for you :)

http://www.2shared.com/file/y8aLzCmg/Print_Exported_Pdf_File.html

Good luck,
Daniel

Comment: Thank you, i'm going to try this one!